# How to apply CanActivate to all path except some

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing

I have a list of path I want to apply `CanActivate` to all path except some path.Is there any way in angular to discard some path.
Currently I am applying `canActivate` to all the URLs.If there are lots of URL,We don't want to apply it to all the URL, I will apply to parent path.
But if we apply to parent it will be applicable to all children also. Is there any way to discard some of the children.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path : '', component: UsersListComponent, canActivate:[AuthenticationGuard] },
    { path : 'add', component : AddComponent, canActivate:[AuthenticationGuard]},
    { path : ':id', component: UserShowComponent },
    { path : 'delete/:id', component : DeleteComponent, canActivate:[AuthenticationGuard] },
    { path : 'ban/:id', component : BanComponent, canActivate:[AuthenticationGuard] },
    { path : 'edit/:id', component : EditComponent, canActivate:[AuthenticationGuard] }
];
```

Comment: Hey, did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to discard some children, but you may break your routes in such a way that Guard applies to some and not to some,

Try below,

```
 {
    path: 'parentPath',
    component: ParentComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path : 'child1', component: ChildComponent1},
      {path : 'child2', component: ChildComponent2}
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'parentPath',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {path : 'child3', component: ChildComponent3}
    ]
  }
```

If you design your routes like above, Guards will only be applied to `child1` and `child2`, and not on `child3`.

In this way you can easily apply Guard at parent level for some of the children.

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TfHG00D8rrKK98I67PTe?p=preview)!!